# Node Cron job for emails

Tags: node.js, angular, nodemailer, cron-task

I am building my first Node + Express app (MEAN) and need to implement automatic email send functionality. User can create a reminder and then mailer will send it on a specific day.

I am thinking to use the default [Nodemailer](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_email.asp) + [Node Schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) and wonder hot to manage this when server goes offline. User Rodrigo Mata proposes to use some packages, but could I do something like:

1. When server starts, fetch all reminders and register cron job if needed;
2. If user adds new reminder, register new cron job;

But there is a problem - how should I know when server goes off line? And how i should I register all cron jobs only once (after server goes on line?)

I create a file that fetches all Reminders and based on a property (`delivered: boolean`) registers a cron job, so I will do it for every new session (when any user visits the page.

p.s. such a "simple" task appears to be quite tricky...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those libraries don't implement real cron jobs, they act like so, but under the hood they are intervals. In other words, you need to keep you app working, so I recommend you initialize it with a package manager like [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) or [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be great if you could provide a bit more info on how those packages works (I'll upvote when repo reaches 15 points)

Comment: Basically they keep your app running and restart it if it somehow crashes if you configure that behaviour. Also, they have embedded monitoring tools that you could use to improve your app performance.

Comment: So they must run my app on their own server, right? And its free...? My head cant chew it, sorry :D But thanks

Comment: Yeah, both are free. For example you run an app with `node myapp.js` so instead of that you run something like `pm2 myapp.js`, just follow the installation steps.